# Forwardable and SingleForwardable differences, use cases?

Tags: ruby

Ruby's stdlib `Forwardable` and `SingleForwardable` are almost the same, please see [this gist](https://gist.github.com/JuanitoFatas/0616985c2ae186023c80) to compare their code.

From the `SingleForwardable`'s documentation it says:

> `SingleForwardable` can be used to setup delegation at the object level as well. Also, `SingleForwardable` can be used to set up delegation for a `Class` or `Module`.

But I see `Forwardable` could also do the job.

What is their main difference and most importantly, what are their use cases? Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For me, it seems almost identical. The only actual difference I see is the

```
  module_eval(str, __FILE__, line_no)
```

added in `Forwardable`.

I guess that `SingleForwardable` was an old version and that `Forwardable` is the new name for it. `Forwardable` looks like extended version of the former.

It also seems that `SingleForwardable` was retrofitted with support for `debug` flag, but note that it's bound back to `Forwardable` class. I guess the `SingleForwardable` was left behind and patched just to not break any old code that already was using that class.

But still, that's a guess.